# When calling a Lotusscript agent from a button on the web, how can I add a spinner so that until the agent is done the user knows it is processing?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a Lotusscript agent behind a submit button that takes a while to do everything....the user needs to know it is processing so that they do not click the button multiple times.

Am using @Command([RunAgent];"agentname") to kick the agent off.

How in Lotusscript could I add some kind of 'processing' indication, either a progress bar or a spinner or something?   I suppose I could embed some javascript inside the lotusscript, but hoping someone has a clean example or some tips to do this.

Maybe hiding the submit button at the same time if I use javascript via a display property on a  surrounding the button would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with LotusScript coding, and while hiding the Submit button is a good idea, you're going to have to know when to unhide it. A simple @Command([RunAgent]...) call won't give you a way to do that.

You're going to have to redesign your form to include a significant amount of JavaScript and make an AJAX-style call to invoke your agent asynchronously via a ?OpenAgent URL sent in a POST request via XMLHttpRequest. Your main JavaScript code will continue after the call and launch the spinner, and the callback that you set up to handle the asynch return from the XMLHttpRequest can then either transition to a new page or stop the spinner by setting a variable that the spinner is checking once every second or two.